# Behavior of Multithreaded programs in different OS

Tags: java, multithreading, oop

How does a multithreaded code written in java behaves differently in different OS. Basically I want to know how threads of same priority are handled in different OS and if there are any other parameters on the basis of which different OS handles a thread.

Comment: Basically: this is the wrong kind of question you ask when you do Java. Thread priorities and whatnot _are not_ parameters you should even consider... Unless you program at a very low level, something which Java cannot do anyway.

Comment: It's not sufficient to say "in different OS".  A program that monkeys around with priorities could behave differently in different JVM implementations on the same OS and hardware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Java threads use the native operating system's threads, so Java threads will behave however native threads do.  However, in most operating systems today, the operating system gives threads of the same priority slices of time in approximately equal amounts.

The main difference between operating systems is that you may find that some threading bugs will occur in some operating systems, but not in others, due to differences in the threading or memory architecture.  Hardware differences can also cause this effect.

The best thing to do is to ensure your code is properly synchronized, without deadlocks or race conditions, so that it will operate safely in any operating system.